# Conectar bd en wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

quiero llamar la información de mi BD en una tabla que se mostrara en user.php de wordpress, hasta el momento no puedo encontrar la manera de que se refleje los datos.

De esta manera estoy haciendo la conexión al a BD

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $qry = 'SELECT * FROM wc_companies  ';
    $inst_sql = $wpdb->prepare($qry);
    $companies = $wpdb->get_row($inst_sql, OBJECT); 
?>
```

De está manera llamo los datos a la tabla

```
<?php 
    foreach ((array) $wc_companies as $wc_companies) {
?>
            <tr class="tr">
                <td class="td"><?php print_r($wc_companies['rut_compaa']); ?></td>
                <td class="td"><?php print_r($wc_companies['nombre_de_sucursal']);?></td>
                <td class="td"><?phpprint_r($wc_companies['ciudad']);?></td>
```

De ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: @excorpion Es SQL

Comment: Si haces un var_dump($companies) que obtienes??? Esto para ver si se estan cargando bien los datos.

Comment: Me regresa NULL

Comment: Y de $inst_sql ??

Comment: Me regresa: string(28) "SELECT * FROM wc_companies "

Comment: Cambia el `prepare` por un `execute` que te devuelve `inst_sql ` en ese caso ?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method wpdb::execute() in /home/creatuid/public_html/wp-content/themes/astra/dev.php:118

Comment: entonces haz primero el prepare, luego el execute como se debe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias cosas en tu código.

1. En primer lugar, si usas [`prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) debes entender que la consulta debe tener marcadores y por tanto **argumentos** los cuales son obligatorios (required). Pero realmente **no necesitas aquí una consulta preparada**, puedes usar [`get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/).
2. En la lectura del `foreach` deberías evitar que el nombre de la variable de la izquierda sea igual que el de la derecha: `foreach ((array) $wc_companies as $wc_companies) {`
3. Si tú indicas que quieres un objeto: `$companies = $wpdb->get_row($inst_sql, OBJECT);` debes saber que la sintaxis para leer propiedades de objeto es `$objeto->propiedad`, no `$objeto['propiedad']`. Lo digo por cosas como esta: `print_r($wc_companies['rut_compaa'])`
4. Considero que no deberías abusar de `print_r`, y usar simplemente una concatenación. De este modo el código es más claro y evitarás errores como este: `<td class="td"><?phpprint_r($wc_companies['ciudad']);?></td>` donde no pones espacio entre `php` y `print_r`
5. Falta rigor en tu código. Debes controlar posibles fallos, de consulta errónea o de resultados vacíos. Debes igualmente abrir una etiqueta `table` adecuadamente, así como cerrarla. También, debes cerrar los `tr`, cosa que no haces. Aquí, para todo, yo he usado una variable `$html`. Si lo que menciono en este punto ya lo tienes, adapta tu código adecuadamente.

Corrigiendo todo lo dicho, el código quedaría así:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    #Evita espacios en blanco sobrantes
    $qry = 'SELECT * FROM wc_companies';
    $companies = $wpdb->get_results($qry, OBJECT);
    if (is_null($companies) || !empty($wpdb->last_error) || !$companies) {
        $html="Error en consulta o no hubo resultados";
    } else {
        $html="<table>";
        foreach ((array) $wc_companies as $wc_companie) {
            $html.=
            "<tr class=\"tr\">
                <td class=\"td\">{$wc_companie->rut_compaa}</td>
                <td class=\"td\">{$wc_companie->nombre_de_sucursal}</td>
                <td class=\"td\">{$wc_companie->ciudad}</td>
             </tr>";
        }
        $html.="</table>";
    }
    echo $html;
?>
```

Debería funcionar, salvo otros errores.